# Apollo Client 3 reset reactive variable to its initial value

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Using Apollo Client 3 and created a reactive varibale as below;

```
 export const carVar = makeVar<Car>({
   brand: '',
   model: '',
   year: '',
   fastEnough: false,
});
```

At some point, I've set its value like this;

```
carVar({ brand: 'BMW', model: 'M4', year: '1991', fastEnough: true });
```

Is it possible to reset `car` variable to its initial value without setting its properties individually?

Comment: You can define your initialValues as constant. And you can use this constant to reset your carVar. ex: carVar(constants.initialValues)

Comment: Thank you @OzanManav.  Using `Partial<T>`  utility from Typescript would be more elegant.

Comment: yes, it is type-safe is solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If we create the cache as below;

```
export function makeCar(
  partial: Partial<Car>
): Car {
  return {
    brand: '',
    model: '',
    year: '',
    fastEnough: false,
    ...partial,
  };
}

export const CarVar = makeVar<Car>(
  makeCar({})
);
```

We can re-initialize out reactive variable partially or totally as we wish;

```
  CarVar(makeCar({}));
```